# How can you change how your Gmail account name appears?

Tags: gmail

Since Google does not recognise using dots (i.e., if you name is "t.smith", you will get mails to `tsmith` and `t.smith`), can you change how your name appears?

In other words, can you change your account name from appearing `t.smith` to `tsmith`?

Answer (score 6):

If your email is `tsmith@gmail.com`, yes you are able to login using `t.smith` or `t.s.m.i.th` and sending emails to `t.sm.ith@gmail.com` or `t.smith+whatever@gmail.com` will end endup in your inbox. But you can't change how it's going to appear once you are logged in. Google will use the username as you wrote it when you created your account.

What you can do though, you can go to your `Gmail Settings` > `Accounts` > `Add another email address you own`, write exactly how you wanted to appear and finally `make default`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean when you send an e-mail ?

- Go to the Gmail Settings (cranted wheel on the top right)
- Go the Account Tab
- Section `Send mail as`
- Click on `Edit info`
- Change your display name