# How to leave empty last name or both in Google Mail?

Tags: gmail, username

For some services it is useful to have one name in the email header. When you create an email account, Google by default does not allow to leave the name field empty.

How to leave empty last name or both in Google Mail?

Comment: Errr...are you talking about you and your email address, or are you talking about some of your contacts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Easy way

1. login to Google Mail
2. open links "Settings > Accounts > Send mail as edit info"
3. change field "Name" to one word
4. Save Changes

---

Hard way - or if you want empty both names

1. login to Google Mail
2. open links "Settings > Accounts > Send mail as > edit info"
3. change field "Name"

or

1. login to Google Apps Admin
2. open links "Users > choose user > Rename"

and

put to inputs special "Unicode Character" [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) or [ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) from "Char map" or online from section "Other Special Non-Printing Characters" https://coolsymbol.com

**Indirect sources**

- [Are recipients of my Gmail emails also given my full name?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/does-my-name-get-sent-along-with-my-email)
- [How can you change how your Gmail account name appears?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24541/how-can-you-change-how-your-gmail-account-name-appears)
- [Chris Calabrese: How To Delete Your Last Name from Your Google/Gmail Account](http://chris.calabrese.org/?p=271)